# What is the difference between InSAR and PolSAR?

Tags: remote-sensing, sar

How to define those two SAR Technologies?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

PolSAR and InSAR are two fundamentally different parameters.

PolSAR looks at different polarities within one observation, so whether the signal is 'vertical' / V, or 'horizontal' H, when the signal was emitted and when it is received. This is why you'll often see a SAR dataset labelled with either VV, VH, HV, or VV (theoretically, VH and HV should be the same).

InSAR looks at the phase of the phase in the signal of two or more observations. The idea here is to look at the difference in phase to identify areas of deformation, such as areas suffering from subsidence.

Overall, the two methodologies have fundamentally different use-cases, with PolSAR being more in line with other remote sensing methodologies and InSAR being quite unique in how it is done and what it can do.